# VM becomes slow after a while - mostly dbus-daemon and polkitd at top

Tags: 18.04, dbus

I am running Ubuntu Bionic as a VM on KVM, and after a few days, the VM
suddenly becomes slow, when I run `top`, I see `dbus-daemon` (high CPU) and `polkitd`.

A reboot fixes it, but I want to know if there is something that I can
do to "fix" the host without a reboot.

Comment: Consider upgrading. Last available kernel? Did you try `dbus-monitor --system` and `dbus-monitor --session`?

Comment: Hmm.. kernel upgrade is not in my control! Do  these commands show if there is some kinda incompatibility ?

Comment: If you don't have sudo privileges you won't be able to do much. Those comands [provide you](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-monitor.1.html) of some info to troubleshoot

Comment: Please post more info on your system.
1) `inxi -F`
2) `htop`
3) How much memory are you assigning to the VM?
4) A copy-paste of the "high CPU" info you found (not as screen capture).Please post more info on your system.
1)  inxi -F

Comment: Perhaps you could setup a script to write to file snapshots to see the evolution of `htop`, `atop`, etc.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio  which package has `inxi` ? I dont have it installed. I have rebooted the VM, I will gather this next time there is a slowdown

Comment: Simply install that package, name is `inxi`.
You would better start gathering that info, so when you see the VM slowing down you have something to compare with.

Comment: How many cores has the VM? If it has one and other tasks are requiring CPU, task switching may be killing the performance. With modern CPUs there are several cores available so I would try to assign more CPU cores to the VM and I would also check that the VM is not swapping due to memory starving or swappiness. Check ```free -h``` to se if you're using swap. If you see graphical desktop you'll need at least 2 GB of RAM for the VM, better if it's 4 GB or more.

Comment: usually I create VMs with with 4 or 8 cores, never just 1.